# Create undeletable file and hidden

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using win32.  I wanna create a hidden and undeletable file using `CreateFile()` if possible.  I haven't tried anything so far because the documentation is complex.
Here is an example where my app would be useful.
Let just say we have two people living in the same room, like in college. One of them Always goes on the other guy's laptop and delete some stuff for fun.  The other guy can make his files undeletable to stop his other friend from deleting his files.  This is just basic example.

Comment: Why do you want to create a file with such properties?

Comment: can you say more about undeleteable? Why would you want to do such?

Comment: Well.. Alot of reasons.  One It would protect people from virus that like to delete files

Comment: How would it protect people from such viruses? And if such files were possible, couldn't a virus create one, to make itself incurable?

Comment: I know how to do this (well sort of... but it's more than just file attributes, and not 100% fool-proof.) But you'll need to convince me that you're really not trying to make a malicious application.

Comment: Okay that is easy I'm not making a malicious app

Comment: @Beta, some really nasty viruses do similar techniques to what I know how to do. It goes into the nitty gritty of how the OS works and setting up access control lists... It's not impossible for all people to delete it, for example: rescue and repair bootable CDs that manipulate the file system don't need to abide by the OS ACL or file system attributes for that matter.

Comment: @Mike, I was thinking you should describe the business problem you're facing and why virtually undeletable files are necessary to for its operation.  Place that information in the body of your question please.

Comment: 600 characters are not enough to describe all of the things that are wrong with that example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to create a hidden and un-deletable file.

The closest you can get is creating a file with the hidden attribute and having a process run at all times to keep the file locked, preventing deletion.

This, of course, doesn't prevent the user from checking 'Show Hidden Files' in folder options, closing the process that has the file locked, or using some application to forcefully unlock the file.

Comment: You can mess with ACLs to make it much more difficult to delete beyond just setting file attributes. However, I see no valid reason for doing that.

Comment: You can write your own FSFD to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with using NTFS permissions to accomplish this? i.e. The two users should have different user accounts, only one of them with administrator privileges. You can't protect users from administrators, or administrators from each other, so the "Deletes for fun" guy should be the plain user.